# Upgrade to .net 4 produces breaks webservice .asmx

Tags: c#, .net, asmx, iis-7.5

I was trying upgrading to .net 4 for my WebForms asp.net project.

Now I'm getting this when I try going to the .asmx webservice.

`Server Error in '/' Application.
Type 'Chickenweb.WebServ.WebServ' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Type 'Chickenweb.WebServ.WebServ' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.`

---

It was because I'm using IIS and was using incorrect Application pool.  Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: do you get this after deploying to an IIS instance, or debugging Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like IIS thinks your .asmx file is a .aspx file. You should check the mappings in IIS to see that .asmx is enabled and properly set up.